# Javascript regex replace affects a single word

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, replace

Lets say I have a function `icon_trans(icon)` that replace expected input with a char as an output. The function works fine as expected but there is a single problem.

When input is for e.g. `showers` the ouput is expected `'`.
When input is `snow moon` or `snowmoon` the output is expected `;`.
When input is sun the output is expected I.

**BUT**, When input is `rain sun` or `rainsun`, the output is `I`, instead of expected `%`.

The reason for this is logical because the regex is patching `rain` and then `sun` and returns sun char which is `I`, instead of `rainsun` one which is `%`.

The same happens for every input which has word `sun` in it (`downpour sun`, `rain sun`, `flurries sun` etc.).

JS fiddle will be at the end of the question.

```
function icon_trans(icon) {
    icon = icon.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // remove whitespace

    var mapObj = {
        showers:"'",
        snowmoon:";",
        downpour:"*",
        rain:"$",
        sleet:"0",
        snow:"9",
        hail:"5",
        downpoursun:"+",
        rainsun:"%",
        flurries:"6",
        flurriessun:"7",
        fog:"<",
        haze:"?",
        lightning:"F",
        cloud:"!",
        cloudsun:'"',
        sun:"I"
    };

    icon = icon.replace(/showers|snowmoon|downpour|rain|sleet|snow|hail|downpoursun|rainsun|flurries|flurriessun|fog|haze|lightning|cloud|cloudsun|sun/gi, function(matched) {
        icVar = mapObj[matched]
    });

    console.log(icVar);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `match()` instead of `replace()`

Comment: Get rid of spaces before doing the replace: `icon = icon.replace(/\s/g, "");`

Comment: Perhaps, you need word boundaries: `/\b(?:showers|snowmoon|downpour|rain|sleet|snow|hail|downpoursun|rainsun|flurries|flurriessun|fog|haze|lightning|cloud|cloudsun|sun)\b/gi`. [**Yes, that is it**](https://jsfiddle.net/mxycuc0n/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how will that match "rain sun" as the OP desires?

Comment: @Pointy: The spaces are removed with `.replace(/\s+/g, '')`, so `/rainsun/` matches `rainsun`. https://jsfiddle.net/mxycuc0n/1/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah, OK! yes that will do it :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that was fast! So easy, please write a comment solution so I can accept it. Also Pointy the spaces are already removed as you can see in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the alternatives into a grouping construct (I suggest a non-capturing group `(?:...)`) and set word boundaries `\b` on both ends:

```
/\b(?:showers|snowmoon|downpour|rain|sleet|snow|hail|downpoursun|rainsun|flurries|flurriessun|fog|haze|lightning|cloud|cloudsun|sun)\b/gi
 ^^^^^                                                                                                                             ^^^
```

See the demo showing how `rain sun` is replaced with `%` (as expected):

```js
function icon_trans(icon) {
    icon = icon.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // remove whitespace

    var mapObj = {
        showers:"'",
        snowmoon:";",
        downpour:"*",
        rain:"$",
        sleet:"0",
        snow:"9",
        hail:"5",
        downpoursun:"+",
        rainsun:"%",
        flurries:"6",
        flurriessun:"7",
        fog:"<",
        haze:"?",
        lightning:"F",
        cloud:"!",
        cloudsun:'"',
        sun:"I"
    };

    icon = icon.replace(/\b(?:showers|snowmoon|downpour|rain|sleet|snow|hail|downpoursun|rainsun|flurries|flurriessun|fog|haze|lightning|cloud|cloudsun|sun)\b/gi, function(matched) {
        icVar = mapObj[matched]
    });

    document.body.innerHTML = icVar;
}  
icon_trans("rain sun");
```

Comment: I love your solution. And that was fast! Appreciated man, will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex basically does `mapObj[icon]` in a very convoluted manner.

```
function icon_trans(icon) {
    icon = icon.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // remove whitespace

    var mapObj = {...};

    return mapObj[icon];
}
```

If you insist on using regexes, here's a less clunky way:

```
icon = icon.replace(/\s+/g, '');

var re = new RegExp('\\b(' + Object.keys(mapObj).join('|') + ')\\b', 'i');
var m = icon.match(re);

return mapObj[m[1]];
```

Comment: Hey. I appreciate your comment and solution tho I've already implemented Wiktors one.